What can a man do to reduce sex urge in Islam apart from fasting
Cure for sexual urge in man in Islam apart from fasting

Learning to lower your gaze, keeping yourself busy with work or dhikr most of the time, avoiding unnecessary contact with ghayri mahram, not eating enough to fill your stomach but eating 2/3 or 1/3 of your hunger, but most importantly, marriage.

As well as fasting. Prophet peace and blessings be upon him prescribed fasting for man who are not married.
